# Different definitions of affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, let $X$ be a set(whose
>   elements we will call points) and suppose we have an operation
>   $$+:X\times V\to X$$ satisfying these properties:
>
> 1) $P+\mathbf{0}=P$ for any $P\in X$.
>
> 2) $(P+\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{y}=P+(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})$ for any $P\in
>  X$ and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in V$.
>
> 3) For any two points $P,Q\in X$ there is a unique vector
>   $\mathbf{v}\in V$ such that $P+\mathbf{v}=Q$. This vector is usually
>   denoted by $\overline{PQ}$.
>
> In this case we call $X$ to be an affine space associated with vector
>   space $V$.

Suppose $Y\subset X$ and $W$ is a subspace of $V$. Then we say that $(Y,W$) is an affine subspace of $(X,V)$ if $(Y,W)$ is an affine space under operation defined  on $(X,V)$.

But after some thoughts I have noticed the following: Any affine subspace $Y$ associated with $W$ can be written as a translation $p+W$ for $p\in Y$.

Indeed, let's take any $p\in Y$ and let's show that $Y=p+W$.

Take any element $y\in Y$ then there is a vector $\mathbf{w}\in W$ such that $p+\mathbf{w}=y
$. In other words, $y=p+\mathbf{w}\in p+W$, i.e. $Y\subset p+W$.

Take any $x\in p+W$ then $x=p+\mathbf{w}$ but since $(Y,W)$ is affine subspace then $p+\mathbf{w}\in Y$, i.e. $x\in Y$. It tells us that $p+W\subset Y$.

Hence $Y=p+W$.

Is this proof correct? Would be very thankful for any remarks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it looks right.

The $Y \subset p + W$ direction leverages condition (3) for the (unique) existence of $\mathbf{w}$. The $p + W \subset Y$ direction uses condition (2) to establish inclusion using the premise that $(Y, W)$ is an affine space.

In fact it is often helpful to intuit affine spaces as shifted linear spaces! Linear spaces must contain the origin $\mathbf{0}$, but affine spaces do not. For instance, this shift is helpful when projecting off-centered data onto off-centered subspaces.

[image]